# Designing a system to apply multiple effects to one or multiple targets

Tags: java, game-engine

I'm currently trying to develop a small game as a hobby project, which contains an automated combat system based on cards. My goal is to make later implementation easier by providing a fluent API, like this:

```
doEffect().to(<target>) // applying 1 effect to 1 target
doEffect().to(<targets>) // applying 1 effect to multiple targets

doMultiple(doEffect1(), doEffect2()).to(...) // applying multiple effects
doEffect1().and(doEffect2()).to(...) // different syntax
```

Apart from providing targets upfront, it should also be possible to have them resolved at runtime, like "target 1 enemy with the lowest life".

When applying multiple effects to the same targets (by either joining them with `doMultiple` or `and`), the targets need to be resolved before any effects, since conditions might change after the first effect and change targets, otherwise. Also, certain effects have `beforeResolve` and `afterResolve` conditions, which should only be executed once before/after all targets have been processed.

The version below is fully functional, but I would like to know, how my design could be optimized, since I haven't been using streams and lambdas for too long:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Effect {
    public void execute(CharacterRelativeContext context);
}
```

```
public abstract class TargetedEffect {
    /**
     * (optional) this is called exactly once, before the effect is applied to
     * any targets
     */
    protected void beforeExecute(CharacterRelativeContext context) {

    }

    /**
     * (optional) this is called exactly once, after the effect has been applied
     * to all targets
     */
    protected void afterExecute(CharacterRelativeContext context) {

    }

    /**
     * applies this effect to a single target. For setup or cleanup
     * functionality that should only be executed once for any amount of
     * targets, use {@link #beforeExecute} or {@link #afterExecute}.
     */
    protected abstract void execute(CharacterRelativeContext context, CharacterState target);

    public Effect to(CharacterState... targets) {
        return targets.length == 1 ? this.to(targets[0]) : this.to(Arrays.asList(targets));
    }

    public Effect to(CharacterState target) {
        return c -> {
            this.beforeExecute(c);
            this.execute(c, target);
            this.afterExecute(c);
        };
    }

    public Effect to(Collection<CharacterState> targets) {
        return c -> {
            this.beforeExecute(c);
            targets.forEach(t -> this.execute(c, t));
            this.afterExecute(c);
        };
    }

    public Effect to(TargetSingle target) {
        return c -> this.to(target.resolve(c)).execute(c);
    }

    public Effect to(TargetMultiple target) {
        return c -> this.to(target.resolve(c)).execute(c);
    }

    public TargetedEffect and(TargetedEffect other) {
        return new Joined(this, other);
    }

    public static TargetedEffect doMultiple(TargetedEffect... effects) {
        return new Joined(effects);
    }

    private static final class Joined extends TargetedEffect {
        private final List<TargetedEffect> effects = new ArrayList<>();

        public Joined(TargetedEffect... effects) {
            Collections.addAll(this.effects, effects);
        }

        @Override
        protected void execute(CharacterRelativeContext context, CharacterState target) {

        }

        @Override
        public Effect to(CharacterState target) {
            return c -> this.effects.forEach(e -> e.to(target).execute(c));
        }

        @Override
        public Effect to(Collection<CharacterState> targets) {
            return c -> this.effects.forEach(e -> e.to(targets).execute(c));
        }

        /**
         * Overriden, so we don't create unnecessary wrapper objects
         */
        @Override
        public TargetedEffect and(TargetedEffect other) {
            this.effects.add(other);
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface TargetSingle {
    public CharacterState resolve(CharacterRelativeContext context);
}
```

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface TargetMultiple {
    public Collection<CharacterState> resolve(CharacterRelativeContext context);
}
```

About the classes that are not shown:

- `CharacterState` contains all mutable variables about a combat actor
- `CharacterRelativeContext` contains convenience methods to access the current character, its allies and enemies. The effect itself might now even need access to it, but `Target<...>` classes use it to resolve targets.

As of now, I might want to add some logic to `TargetedEffect.Joined()` and `TargetedEffect.Joined.and()` to check whether it gets passed other `Joined`-instances and break them down into their subeffects first.

Comment: What is the question? If you want your code to be reviewed, consider using [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I didn't actually know about that site, thank you. But yeah, that's basically it. I know it's working but would like to know ways to improve it.